# Multiple line text entry box in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In python i have been making a text editor like Microsoft word but i don't know how to make a text entry box for the user to put input. Here is my code! (ps thank you!)

```
from tkinter import *
import sys


def doNothing():
    print("Test")


root = Tk()
root.title("TextEditor")
root.geometry("300x200")
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", command =doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo",command=doNothing)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
TextArea = Text()
TextArea.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

If you want a scrollbar with it:

```
TextArea = Text()
ScrollBar = Scrollbar(root)
ScrollBar.config(command=TextArea.yview)
TextArea.config(yscrollcommand=ScrollBar.set)
ScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
TextArea.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

Hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was perfect for what i needed!

Comment: @AndyWittig On the left of my answer, underneath the voting options is a checkmark.  If you click it it will move my answer to the top so that other people can find it easier, and so people know your problem was resolved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question but currently following is a very good method for scrollable multiline text entry:

```
ScrolledText(mainwin, width=50, height=5).pack()
```

Full program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

mainwin = Tk()
ScrolledText(mainwin, width=50, height=5).pack()
mainwin.mainloop()
```

Following demo application shows its usage further and comparison with entry box (for python3):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

mainwin = Tk()
Label(mainwin, text="An Entry Box:").grid(row=0, column=0)
ent = Entry(mainwin, width=70); ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(mainwin, text="Print Entry", command=(lambda: print(ent.get()))).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="EW")

Label(mainwin, text="ScrolledText Box:").grid(row=1, column=0)
st = ScrolledText(mainwin, height=5); st.grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(mainwin, text="Print Text", command=(lambda: print(st.get(1.0, END)))).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="EW")

Button(mainwin, text="Exit", command=sys.exit).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="EW")
mainwin.mainloop()
```